# How to pass STDIN to a program and store its output to a variable? C

Tags: c, bash, exec, stdin, system-calls

I need to execute a file from the bash using and store its output to a variable, there's also the needs to pass to its stdin a string *s*. Something like this in bash:

```
    usr:~$ s | program args
```

I know how to call the program and give him args:

```
    execvp(program,args);
```

So my problem is giving to that his stdin and store output to a variable(string)!

P.S.:can't use system and popen.

Comment: Have a look at `popen`

Comment: i can't use neither popen :(

Comment: What *can* you use?

Comment: everything except those two and sleep, but i didn't specify sleep cause it's kinda useless for that...

Comment: Use `pipe`, `fork`, `dup2` and `execvp` to implement your own `popen`-equivalent

Comment: I'm kinda struggling in the making of that. But i'll spent more time to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example code for you to experiement. This excute `ls | cat`.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     int fd[2];
     int pid;
     char* cmd1[2] = {"ls", NULL};
     char* cmd2[2] = {"cat", NULL};
     int status;

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) {
         pipe(fd);
         pid = fork();
         if (pid == 0) {
             printf("cmd1\n");
             dup2(fd[1], 1);
             close(fd[0]);
             close(fd[1]);
             execvp(cmd1[0], cmd1);
             printf("Error in execvp\n");
         }
         else {
             dup2(fd[0], 0);
             close(fd[0]);
             close(fd[1]);
             printf("cmd2\n");
             execvp(cmd2[0], cmd2);
             printf("Error in execvp\n");
         }
     }
     else {
         close(fd[0]);
         close(fd[1]);
         wait(&status);
         printf("%d\n", status);
         wait(&status);
         printf("%d\n", status);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I can see that you use dup2 to copy fd to stdin in order to give the input to cat(?). But i'm not getting the conditions with the fork and also where the output should be saved...

Comment: You can refer to `pipe` and `fork` documentation. Some examples can be easily found. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pipe-system-call/ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/.

Comment: Ok so every condition is made to separate processes achievement, but why do you print error in execvp? Could it be because it should kill the process if successful?

Comment: The line should never be executed. `execvp` never return. Refer to its documentation

Comment: Oh ok so i undestood well that. Everything is clear now, but my last doubt is about the location where the output is stored, i see the the closing condition but there's only an int that wait for other processes to be done. So where should it be my output string?

Comment: The output of `ls` goes to `cat`. This is handled by pipe fds. The output of `cat` goes to stdout.

Comment: Like i thought, but i need to save that in a char array and also can't print on the screen. Maybe i need to redirect to the pipe but that's another problem...